# Unable to use my variable in another function

Tags: python

I am having trouble using my stop variable to do the calculations

```
def main():
    passname=None
    passadult=None
    passchild=None
    morepassengers=True
    names=list()
    adultnumbs=list()
    childnumbs=list()
    totals=list()
    stops=list()
    adultprices=list()
    childprices=list()
    totalprices=list()

wash_to_balt_adult = 20
wash_to_balt_child = 10
wash_to_philly_adult = 25
wash_to_philly_child = 10
wash_to_ny_adult = 30
wash_to_ny_child = 15

def welcome():
    print("Welcome to Kevin's Travel Service!")

def myname():
    print('Written by: Kevin B')
    print('Written on date: Feb 26,2023')

def stops_prices():

        #Prompt user on where they are stopping at
        print("\nThe stops for the bus stops at are Baltimore, Philiadelphia, and New York.\n")
        print('The price from Washington to Baltimore is: $' + str(wash_to_balt_adult),'for adults, $'+ str(wash_to_balt_child),'for children.\n')

        print('The price from Washington to Philiadelphia is: $' + str(wash_to_philly_adult),'for adults, $' + str(wash_to_philly_child),'for children.\n')

        print('The price from Washington to New York is: $' + str(wash_to_ny_adult),'for adults, $' + str(wash_to_ny_child),'for children.\n')


def passinfo():
    validname = False
    adultnumb = ""
    childnumb = ""

    # Prompt user on where they are departing bus to
    stop = int(input("\n\nWhere are you getting off the bus at? Please enter 1 for Baltimore, 2 for Philadelphia, or 3 for New York, <Enter> to exit:\t"))

    # Validate stop
    while not validname:
        if stop < 1 or stop > 3:
            stop = int(input("Invalid number. Please enter 1 for Baltimore, 2 for Philadelphia, or 3 for New York: "))
        else:
            validname = True

    adultnumb = int(input("How many adults? "))
    adultnames = []
    for number in range(adultnumb):
        print("\nAdult", number+1)
        name = input("What is the passenger's name? ")
        adultnames.append(name)

    childnumb = int(input("\nHow many children? "))
    childnames = []
    for number in range(childnumb):
        print("\nChild", number+1)
        name = input("What is the passenger's name? ")
        childnames.append(name)
      
        print ('\n# of Adults: ',adultnumb,'\n# of Children: ',childnumb,'\nWhich Stop: ',stop,'\nName of Adults: ',adultnames,'\nName of Children: ',childnames,'\n')
        
if stop == 1:
          # Calculate the cost for adults going to Baltimore
          adultprice = adultnumb * 20
          print(adultprice)
          # Calculate the cost for children going to Baltimore
          childprice = childnumb * 10
          print(childprice)
          totalprice = adultprice + childprice

          print(totalprice)

elif stop == 2:
          # Calculate the cost for adults going to Philadelphia
          adultprice = adultnumb * 25
          print(adultprice)
          # Calculate the cost for children going to Philadelphia
          childprice = childnumb * 10
          print(childprice)
          totalprice = adultprice + childprice

          print(totalprice)

elif stop == 3:
          # Calculate the cost for adults going to New York
          adultprice = adultnumb * 30
          print(adultprice)
          childprice = childnum * 15
          print(childprice)
          totalprice = adultprice + childprice

          print(totalprice)


#    return totalprice,adultprice,childprice

main()

welcome()
print('\n')
myname()
print('\n')
passinfo()
print('\n')
```

I don't know why the stop variable is failing
I don't know why the stop variable is failing
I don't know why the stop variable is failing
I don't know why the stop variable is failing
I don't know why the stop variable is failing
I don't know why the stop variable is failing

Comment: The variables declared in `main` don’t exist outside that function.  This might be a good time to learn about objects and classes, since that’s an easy way for related functions to share variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because **if else** conditions are written outside the block of `passinfo()` in which `stop` is defined

Here is the modified code:

```
def main():
    passname=None
    passadult=None
    passchild=None
    morepassengers=True
    names=list()
    adultnumbs=list()
    childnumbs=list()
    totals=list()
    stops=list()
    adultprices=list()
    childprices=list()
    totalprices=list()

wash_to_balt_adult = 20
wash_to_balt_child = 10
wash_to_philly_adult = 25
wash_to_philly_child = 10
wash_to_ny_adult = 30
wash_to_ny_child = 15

def welcome():
    print("Welcome to Kevin's Travel Service!")

def myname():
    print('Written by: Kevin B')
    print('Written on date: Feb 26,2023')

def stops_prices():

        #Prompt user on where they are stopping at
        print("\nThe stops for the bus stops at are Baltimore, Philiadelphia, and New York.\n")
        print('The price from Washington to Baltimore is: $' + str(wash_to_balt_adult),'for adults, $'+ str(wash_to_balt_child),'for children.\n')

        print('The price from Washington to Philiadelphia is: $' + str(wash_to_philly_adult),'for adults, $' + str(wash_to_philly_child),'for children.\n')

        print('The price from Washington to New York is: $' + str(wash_to_ny_adult),'for adults, $' + str(wash_to_ny_child),'for children.\n')


def passinfo():
    validname = False
    adultnumb = ""
    childnumb = ""

    # Prompt user on where they are departing bus to
    stop = int(input("\n\nWhere are you getting off the bus at? Please enter 1 for Baltimore, 2 for Philadelphia, or 3 for New York, <Enter> to exit:\t"))

    # Validate stop
    while not validname:
        if stop < 1 or stop > 3:
            stop = int(input("Invalid number. Please enter 1 for Baltimore, 2 for Philadelphia, or 3 for New York: "))
        else:
            validname = True

    adultnumb = int(input("How many adults? "))
    adultnames = []
    for number in range(adultnumb):
        print("\nAdult", number+1)
        name = input("What is the passenger's name? ")
        adultnames.append(name)

    childnumb = int(input("\nHow many children? "))
    childnames = []
    for number in range(childnumb):
        print("\nChild", number+1)
        name = input("What is the passenger's name? ")
        childnames.append(name)
      
        print ('\n# of Adults: ',adultnumb,'\n# of Children: ',childnumb,'\nWhich Stop: ',stop,'\nName of Adults: ',adultnames,'\nName of Children: ',childnames,'\n')
        
    if stop == 1:
              # Calculate the cost for adults going to Baltimore
              adultprice = adultnumb * 20
              print(adultprice)
              # Calculate the cost for children going to Baltimore
              childprice = childnumb * 10
              print(childprice)
              totalprice = adultprice + childprice
    
              print(totalprice)
    
    elif stop == 2:
              # Calculate the cost for adults going to Philadelphia
              adultprice = adultnumb * 25
              print(adultprice)
              # Calculate the cost for children going to Philadelphia
              childprice = childnumb * 10
              print(childprice)
              totalprice = adultprice + childprice
    
              print(totalprice)
    
    elif stop == 3:
              # Calculate the cost for adults going to New York
              adultprice = adultnumb * 30
              print(adultprice)
              childprice = childnum * 15
              print(childprice)
              totalprice = adultprice + childprice
    
              print(totalprice)
    

#    return totalprice,adultprice,childprice

main()

welcome()
print('\n')
myname()
print('\n')
passinfo()
print('\n')
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

The if statements that begin with:

```
if stop == 1:
```

are not indented enough to be 'in' the function. Those lines of code run before your functions are called. It seems as if you meant to include them in the function, perhaps. In some IDEs you can highlight all of those lines of code and simply hit tab to indent them.